# No StorageClass found in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am currently setting up a Kubernetes cluster but I noticed there are no default storage classes defined.

```
u@n:~$ kubectl get sc                                                                         
No resources found in default namespace.
```

When reading through the docs there are lots of examples for storage classes used when you're deploying your cluster on cloud providers, but not self hosted. What kind of storage class do I need to use in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with self hosted you also mean that you are using a bare-metal Kubernetes cluster (aka you installed Kubernetes on some machines), then you probably need to provide your own storage solution (like you needed to provide a network plugin and an Ingress controller).

---

Sure, you can use local storage, that is always an option.. but such storage is not resilient to node failures, unless the application using it is resilient to node failure on its own.

For certain apps (such as Kafka, ElasticSearch, multi-primary databases such as galera and so on) it may be ok to use local storage, which means that data is available directly on a path munted from a node.. and only on that particular node.

Having data only on a specific node means that the Pod that needs that data (aka that requires the PVC bounded to that path with a PV) is bound to run on that singular node and cannot run on any other.. which means it is not resilient to failures at all.

But, like I said, it may be ok if the application is composed of more than one Pods and can survive if the majority of the Pods is still up and running.

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/

---

Another option is to go with Rook (which is a storage operator) and using Ceph you could provide your own HA storage infrastructure on top of your Kubernetes cluster.

You basically need to provide empty disks and resources to run the Ceph infrastructure on top of your cluster and you'll have Ceph block storage class available (and more) which means volumes resilients to node failures (depending on how much nodes and disks are available to Ceph, of course) and that can be requested from any node.

It's a complex infrastructure to put on a cluster, but it's really stable and can be a valid option for non-test clusters.

https://rook.io/

---

There are a lot of other options and products, a good list on the documentation which can help you decide what you want to use, based on what are your necessities:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can start from the Kubernetes documentation. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner) you can find storage-classes concept. Each StorageClass has a provisioner that determines what volume plugin is used for provisioning PVs. This field must be specified. [local volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local) could help you. Look at the example:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Local volumes do not currently support dynamic provisioning, however a StorageClass should still be created to delay volume binding until Pod scheduling. This is specified by the  `WaitForFirstConsumer`  volume binding mode.

Delaying volume binding allows the scheduler to consider all of a Pod's scheduling constraints when choosing an appropriate PersistentVolume for a PersistentVolumeClaim.

If you are looking for complete guide to configure storage for bare metal cluster you can find it [here](https://www.weave.works/blog/kubernetes-faq-configure-storage-for-bare-metal-cluster). As I mentioned before local volumes do not currently support dynamic provisioning. However it could be workaround, if you are using NFS Server. Look at [this guide](https://geoffreymahugu.medium.com/kubernetes-bare-metal-dynamic-storage-allocation-e5311ac45909).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the StorageClass object -

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

The provisioner value will determine which Volume plugin is being used to provision the Persistent Volumes. In this case, it is AWS EBS. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner) is the list of provisioners.

The parameters-->type value determines the Volume type used. In case of [AWS EBS Volume types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html), gp2 is the default Volume type.

You can get more details on Storage Classes from [Kubernetes Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/).

Comment: apparently OP asked for self hosted solution.